# Replacing Text inside a Label Using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, function

Probably a very simple issue to fix but I'm not very experienced in jQuery. I've tried Googling the issue but I can't seem to find an alternative function or perhaps I'm doing this one wrong.

So essentially when I load the page the HTML is as follows:

```
<div class="control control-department">
    <label><input type="radio" name="department" value="residential-sales">Residential Sales</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="department" value="residential-lettings"> Residential Lettings</label>
</div>
```

Then I'm using some jQuery to replace the text of the buttons e.g. Residential Sales with Buy with the following code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.control-department label:nth-child(1)').text('BUY');
    $('.control-department label:nth-child(2)').text('RENT');
});
```

However once the jQuery has run it then gives me the following HTML and removes the `<input>`. Any ideas on how I can get it to just replace the "Residential Sales" and "Residential Lettings" parts rather than the whole thing?

```
<div class="control control-department">
    <label>BUY</label>
    <label>RENT</label>
</div>
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately the answer within this doesn't help or work either, but thank you anyways. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

JQuery `contents()` also returns text nodes, you can replace text like so:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.control-department label:nth-child(1)').contents().last().replaceWith('BUY');
    $('.control-department label:nth-child(2)').contents().last().replaceWith('RENT');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="control control-department">
    <label><input type="radio" name="department" value="residential-sales">Residential Sales</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="department" value="residential-lettings"> Residential Lettings</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
//loop through label
  $(".control-department label").each(function(i) {
    var child = $(this).children();//save children
    i % 2 == 0 ? $(this).text('BUY') : $(this).text('RENT')//change text
    $(this).prepend(child)//prepend children again
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="control control-department">
  <label><input type="radio" name="department" value="residential-sales">Residential Sales</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="department" value="residential-lettings"> Residential Lettings</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using an array of text replacements could simplify the thing...

Then the trick just is about storing the `input` before changing the text and then restore the `input` where it was.

```js
let replacements = ["BUY", "RENT"]

$(".control-department label").each(function(index){
  
  // Temporarilly store the input
  let input = $(this).find("input")
  
  // Change the text using the replacement array
  this.innerText = replacements[index]
  
  // Re-inject the input
  $(this).prepend(input)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="control control-department">
  <label><input type="radio" name="department" value="residential-sales">Residential Sales</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="department" value="residential-lettings"> Residential Lettings</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

1.HTML

```
<div class="control control-department">
<input type="radio" name="department" value="residential-sales"><label class="label-1">Residential Sales</label>
<input type="radio" name="department" value="residential-lettings"> <label class="label-2">Residential Lettings</label>
```

2.JS:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('.control-department .label-1').text('BUY');
$('.control-department .label-2').text('RENT');
```

});

Explanation:

1. The way you used `label` is wrong
2. When you replaced text inside the label it included the input radio button as well, which is fixed by restructing it a bit.

Edit:
**Solution 2**

Since you can't change the HTML structure, try this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

$('.control-department label:nth-child(1)').html('<input type="radio" name="department" value="residential-sales">Buy');
$('.control-department label:nth-child(2)').html('<input type="radio" name="department" value="residential-sales">Rent');
```

});

Comment: Sorry, as it's a plugin I'm using I cannot alter the structure of the inputs and labels. What I have here is what I need to work with unfortunately. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @LewisHardisty Well, in that case you can still restructure the jQuery part to get your work done, let me know if you want me to provide you a code for the same

Comment: Thanks, if you could provide the complete code I'd need to restructure the HTML and then replace the text that would be perfect, I'd appreciate that a lot!

Comment: @LewisHardisty this should work:

$( document ).ready(function() {
// console.log($('.control-department label:nth-child(1)').contents()[0]);
    $('.control-department label:nth-child(1)').html('<input type="radio" name="department" value="residential-sales">Buy');
    $('.control-department label:nth-child(2)').html('<input type="radio" name="department" value="residential-sales">Rent');
});